# Webpart not displaying sharepoint view properly

Tags: sharepoint-online

some background on my issue faced:

1. I have created a Sharepoint list with two different views - All items view (as the name suggests, it shows all items in the Sharepoint list without filtering), as well as Management view (where I created the public view and applied certain filters to massage the view and show by certain sales team only)
2. Separately, I have created a page and added a web part in the page to show the list (objective is to show Management View), and have set the view to "Management View" in the list settings
3. When I saved my page, I can see from my end the web part is displaying correctly per my setting (i.e. List displaying Management View) - however when I share across the page link to my user, they dont see what I see, but only see the web part showing All items view instead.

Any input or advice on this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the page, you have to save the web part as well (with the `Apply` button). So you need two clicks: one for the view (Apply) and the second for the page (Publish or Republish). If you forgot to save the webpart, the page will display the wrong view.

[image: Apply button]

Comment: Thank you - have confirmed that I have clicked on "Apply" and subsequently "Republish" the page for the page to get updated - hence that's why on my end when I click on the page link as a user I can see the web part is configured in the way that I expected, but strange thing is when I share the page with my user it doesn't.